# I downloaded Kubuntu 15.04 onto my computer

Tags: kubuntu

I am (running Windows XP) now it is sitting in an ISO file on my computer. When I try to open it a window comes up that says "Windows cannot open this file" Not sure where to go from here. This is my first experience trying to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: How much memory do you have and do you know your processor speed? I would burn that ISO file to a CD and try launching up kbuntu in live mode and if you like it install from the CD you create.

Answer (score 2):

Kubuntu is an operating system not a windows executable file.  In order to run Kubuntu, you need to burn the ISO to a CD, DVD or flash drive and boot from that device.

Kubuntu ISO is a Live CD so you can boot your computer to it and not harm or affect your Windows system. It will allow you to use Kubuntu until you get used to it, or when you are comfortable, you can install it on your HDD, or a separate HDD right next to Windows XP.  Then you can choose to boot on XP or Kubuntu.

An alternative is to install a Virtual Machine (VM) program and run Kubuntu in the VM while running XP.  Virtual Box is a great tool for that.  However, it will run slower and use up a lot of your resources operating inside XP.

Either way, you can work with Kubuntu and get to know it before installing it or without removing or damaging XP.